# How can I run a service for multiple VLAN's?

Tags: vlan, network-interface, alpine-linux

I have a running server hosted on 192.168.254.1 with some VLAN's which can be accessed by each one from 192.168.(TAG).1. I'm trying to run a service on a second computer physically connected to the first one and make it available for all VLAN's by running it on 192.168.(TAG).1 for each VLAN.

This second computer runs Alpine Linux with [vlan package](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Vlan) added and have interface configuration for physical interfaces like this

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.254.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.254.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.254.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.254.1
```

And for every VLAN on network like this

```
auto eth1.(TAG)
iface eth1.(TAG) inet static
    address 192.168.(TAG).2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.(TAG).1
```

But the service only can be accessed by the server computer on IP 192.168.254.2.

When trying to ping 192.168.254.1 from the second computer, I had response only when pinging from eth0.

Is there anything I can do to run this service?

Comment: As it’s written it’s hard to make heads or tails of what you are saying. Please re-read your post and [edit] it so it makes better sense.

Comment: eth0 and eth1 have the same IP address.

Comment: I tried changing eth1 IP address and it still didn't work

Comment: Why are they in the same subnet at all?